# Restrict access to resources in AWS based on name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to restrict the user to have access to only the resources starting with a particular string. For example, I would like to restrict the user with all permissions to only RDS instances starting with `"new-database-change"`. Basically, in regex it would be `"new-database-change-*"`. The application is far ahead and we missed using tags. Is there anyway we could do this without tags?
Something of the following would do.

```
 {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:AddTagsToResource",
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusters",
                "rds:RestoreDBClusterToPointInTime",
                "rds-db:connect",
                "rds:CreateDBInstance",
                "rds:DeleteDBInstance"
            ],
            "Resource": "new-database-change-*"
        }
```

The AWS currently takes the literal "*" and not the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this.

In reviewing [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon RDS - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html):

- `AddTagsToResource` does not take `rds:DatabaseName` as a Condition
- `DescribeDBInstances` and `DescribeDBClusters` do not take any conditions -- they always returns *ALL* results
- `RestoreDBClusterToPointInTime` does not take `rds:DatabaseName` as a Condition

Not sure about `rds-db:connect` -- it can accept an ARN, but not sure if it can accept a database name.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the code to include delete as well. I am assuming that cannot be done too.

Comment: Check the `Conditions` column on the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a wildcard resource and a restricted policy [condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html#amazonrds-policy-keys), for example:

```
"Resource": "*",
"Condition": {"StringLike": {"rds:DatabaseName": "new-database-change-*"}}
```

Comment: I edited the comment to include delete operation. I still get the same error `DeleteDBInstance operation: User: arn:aws:iam::000000:user/abc is not authorized to perform: rds:DeleteDBInstance on resource`

Comment: For actions that require an ARN (as opposed to am RDS database name), you can't use rds:DatabaseName. You can investigate tagging the RDS instances and then apply IAM conditional policies on [rds:db-tag/${TagKey}](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html#amazonrds-policy-keys).